# Adnominalisation (Relative clause - noun - copula structure): What does it mean? How can we translate it?

Tags: translation, usage, copula, relative-clauses

I have two examples of this structure which does not obviously correspond to a pattern in English although it is quite common. I'd like to know what it means, why it is used and how it should be translated (because if I can do that I know I understand it).

**Example 1**

I heard this on a TV series yesterday.  The final scene of one part portrayed two sisters, かよ and はな. かよ was grieving over the death of her fiance and はな could not say anything to her and get a calm reasonable response.  The narrator said:

> かよに何も言えないはなでした。ごきげんよう、さよなら。
>
> [FINIS]

It is easy to reword this final sentence as

> はなはかよに何も言えなかったんだ。

And capture most of the literal meaning. In English I might have narrated, "Hana could not say anything to Kayo." or perhaps "Poor Hana, as far as Kayo was concerned, what ever Hana said, it was the wrong thing to say." but something, I am not sure what, is missing.

**Example 2**

The following is the final paragraph from a magazine article on how convenience stores have developed over the past 40 years, particularly since the earthquake in March 2011:

> 誕生から４０年、柔軟に形を変えながら成長してきたコンビニ。次は、どんなサービスを展開し、どう進化していくのか。楽しみである。

This is in "newspaper Japanese" so the copula is omitted. I would have written:

> コンビニは誕生から４０年、柔軟に形を変えながら成長(してきた)。

In both examples the writers seem to have deliberately chosen this "relative clause - noun - copula" structure (in the second case a zero copula).  We have some questions on 体言止め　help with my first question below I should be grateful if somebody could explain:

1) Why or when is this structure used?
2) How it should be translated? (because if I can do that I know I understand it).
3) Are there any redundant subjects/topics omitted because they not necessary?  (eg 
If we take AはBでした as a complete sentence then in example 1 we have "Bでした" but not "Aは"）

---

*Supplementary note*
Last night I thought I had a new example from the TV. After a doing bungy jump a woman said to the camera 「挑戦してよかった、あたし」. It sounded like the construction in example one. Then I realised it is just an example of somebody inverting the order of the parts a spoken sentence. It may just be coincidence but the similarity of how this exclamation and example one sounded to me as a listener (and how the information is received) struck me.)

Comment: I think it's extremely common in novels and comic books. It sounds to me like: freeze-frame = stage + actor です/でした.

Comment: I think a lot of headlines have this structure, e.g. here's one from Yomiuri: "新聞読み「自分では」警察に電話したひき逃げ男". I too wonder what would the correct translation be for these kind of sentences.

Comment: We discussed this a little here: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/strange-use-of-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F-in-narrative

Comment: @Hyperworm : Scene setting sounds right. I have added more context to example 1 - it was the closing statement by the narrator in one part of a series, so perhaps it was setting the scene for next episode. In example 2 it seems to be setting the scene for the final sentence given. It is difficult to translate - I am sure there must some subjects/topics omitted because they can be understood from the context.

Comment: I added a new tag, [tag:information-structure], for discussions of different ways to structure the same information; also called **information packaging** because the information is the same as in a basic sentence, but it's packaged differently: "I ate the cake" versus "It was I who ate the cake", or "A man was walking down the street" versus "There was a man walking down the street", etc.  Maybe we could find some older related questions and tag them, too.

Comment: @Tim, I think でした is just a summary of what has happened. It functions like a _caption_ . I don't find such techniques used in Chinese dramas, movies, narrations and comics, so I guess it's Japanese-specific. Japanese literature particularly likes 体言止め.

Comment: Is this a form of [cleft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence)?

Comment: @leoboiko I don't think so but is an interesting thought and I am not an expert on this.  If something is being omitted then that might be part the explanation but I could not see an easy answer from the following paper (?): Can you suggest what the full "clefted" sentence would be?  http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~ctjhuang/Course_LSA222/readings/Saito.2004.cleft.pdf

Answer (score 4):

How about using the English copula in this case too?
"And there **was** Hanako, lost for words to comfort her sister, Kayo"

Or in the case of the second, "the" could work too:
"**The** ever evolving convenience store: with 40 years since its inception, blah blah blah"

As for meaning, it doesn't mean anything special per se, but to me it feels "defining" for lack of a better word, or like something used in narrative (like your example). Almost like the tone used in English nature documentaries if that helps:

"The fickle and mysterious domestic cat: superb hunter and ubiquitous human companion animal"

Comment: Brandon, @Yang Muye Thank you. I think this is common expression too. Those are interesting suggestions - have you seen such translations in practice or heard an explanation for what effect this construction has?

Answer (score 4):

When there is no copula and nothing seems to be omitted, as in your second example, I interpret the sentence as simply a **fragment**, used to "set the scene", and would translate it as such. It is very reminiscent of how fragments are used in descriptive passages in English:

> Pale druggists in remote towns of the Epworth League and flannel nightgown belts, endlessly wrapping up bottles of Peruna. . . . Women hidden away in the damp kitchens of unpainted houses along the railroad tracks, frying tough beefsteaks. . . . Lime and cement dealers being initiated into the Knights of Pythias, the Red Men or the Woodmen of the World. . . . Watchmen at lonely railroad crossings in Iowa, hoping that they'll be able to get off to hear the United Brethren evangelist preach. . . . Ticket-sellers in the subway, breathing sweat in its gaseous form. . . . Farmers plowing sterile fields behind sad meditative horses, both suffering from the bites of insects. . . . Grocery-clerks trying to make assignations with soapy servant girls. . . . Women confined for the ninth or tenth time, wondering helplessly what it is all about. . . . Methodist preachers retired after forty years of service in the trenches of God, upon pensions of $600 a year.
>
> -- H. L. Mencken, taken from [here](http://grammar.about.com/od/rhetoricstyle/a/effectivefrag.htm)

Compare the above with this short Japanese passage that is clearly going for a similar, if not identical, effect:

> 何者かが何者かに切り殺されている気配。嘆き。叫び。 … 血塗られた背と折れた剣、砕けた柱……。
>
> Hints of someone being slashed and slain by someone. Wails. Cries. ... A back smeared with blood and a broken sword, a crumbled pillar....

And your example translated in this way:

> 誕生から４０年、柔軟に形を変えながら成長してきたコンビニ。
>
> The convenience store that has grown while limberly changing shape, 40 years since its inception.

The form and function seem quite similar. There's practically no limit to how much the noun can be modified, be it adjectivally, adverbially, relatively, or phrasally. And what we get in effect is a snapshot, a picture, an isolated concept. The focus is not on what the noun *is*, *does*, *did*, etc, but on the very noun itself.

---

When the copula is present, as in your first example, I don't see how the sentence is any different in form from 「私です。」, as in response to 「誰ですか？」, only with additional modifiers:

> かよに何も言えないはなでした。
>
> It was a Hana who couldn't say anything to Kayo.

And before I get bashed for abusing English, let me just say that modifying proper nouns--and pronouns!--with the help of definite/indefinite articles is a well-established practice:

> Mr Dursley hummed as he picked out his most boring tie for work and Mrs Dursley gossiped away happily as she wrestled **a screaming Dudley** into his highchair. -- J.K. Rowling
>
> **The me I was yesterday** is no more. Let **the me of tomorrow** come!

ASIDE: Brandon's suggestion is definitely more natural and would work in practice. However, I feel that it's more a translation of the following:

> そこで、かよに何も言えないはながいました。
>
> And there was Hana, unable to say anything to Kayo.

With there-insertion, *was* is no longer the *linking-verb be*, but the *existential be*.

---

EDIT: How does the Hana sentence fit as a narrative of the scenario? Why the relative-noun-copula structure?

Again, here's the sentence in question, with what I believe to be the omitted topic:

> (それは)かよに何も言えないはなでした。

A `subject + が` doesn't seem likely here.

I don't believe this sentence is making a statement about Hana. If it were, it would instead be 「はなはかよに何も言えなかったんだ。」, your suggestion. Rather, it is a statement on the **general state of affairs**, quite fitting for an ending narration.

The distinction may not be obvious. To illustrate, I'll appeal to English's *It*, as the general-state-of-affairs idea is inherent in certain usages of *It*.

Consider the "[weather it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun#Weather_it)":

> (1) It is raining.
>
> (2) It is cold.

What might *It* be referring to?

In (1), one might argue that *It = Rain*, `Rain is raining.`, where *to rain* means *to fall*. (Interestingly, this is how (1) is expressed in Japanese: 「雨が降っている。」)

However, the idea that the "weather it" refers to something concrete is problematic, especially in (2), where it is not obvious what that something is. The weather is cold? The air? The surrounding area? And yet everyone seems to understand the sentence perfectly fine! Thus, some linguists argue that *It* here simply refers to the **general state of affairs**.

Also, note how (2) is expressed in Japanese: 「寒いです。」, an `X + copula` construction. If we accept that Japanese's `X + copula` is similar to English's `It + copula` in that both can be statements on the general state of affairs, then it would not be too much a stretch to say that the difference between 「(それは)かよに何も言えないはなでした。」 and 「はなはかよに何も言えなかったんだ。」 is akin to the difference between "It was a cold day." and "The day was cold."

Hence, "It was a Hana who couldn't say anything to Kayo." (The general state of affairs: a Hana who couldn't say anything to Kayo.)

Evidence from literature:

> **It was** the best of times, **it was** the worst of times. -- Charles Dickens
>
> **それは** すべての時世の中で最もよい時世 **でもあれば**、すべての時世の中で最も悪い時世 **でもあった**。

Comment: (Updated) Thank you. I like the wide choice of writers! The second example seems to work but I am not quite sure how your translation for the first one, about Hana, works as a the narrative for the scenario (context) I have described. It is a faithful translation but I prefer my own suggestion ("Hana could not say anything to Kayo."), unfortunately  it is derived from the un-nominalised sentence and therefore not a faithful translation.  Even so, I am all hears to hear why you are right...

Comment: @Tim Expanded my answer in response to your comment.

Comment: Thank you, it is very helpful to have someone challenge my understanding (which does not make sense to me).  I have some comments on your answer: First, I have always taken the "It is cold (outside)" to be "The weather is cold (outside)."[I added "outside" just to show "It" is not necessarily the place ("Tokyo is cold.")] and this corresponds quite well with 「「天気は寒いです。」. I take 雨が降っている to mean "Rain is falling/coming down.", it is similar to "The sun is shining." and does not feel uncomfortable in English. (cont'd)

Comment: Although it more common to say "It is raining.", "The sun is shining." is a reasonable alternative to "It is sunny." and better than "The weather is sunny." because (to me) it is obvious what you are talking about.

Comment: The challenge in example one is the translation. I can accept everything in your answer except your translation which still does not fit as a narrative aswell as mine, and this particular narrator uses this structure a lot.(cont'd)

Comment: Your answer prompts the thought that the transformation in example one is similar to "[As for the weather] The sun is shining"<-> "[As for the weather] It is sunny." (?) and "The rain is falling." <-> "It is raining.". Although both work in the case of the sun, we are much less likely to say "The rain is falling.": After reading your answer, I am inclined to think that just as  「雨が降っています』is often better translated as "It is raining.", so this narrative is better translated the way I have suggested.

Comment: To me, the "it" in "it is obvious what you are talking about" or "it is hard to juggle" *might* be a clearer example of general-state-of-affairs "it".

Comment: @3to5businessdays : Whatever, can we find a translation for example 1 that fits better my effort? [FWIW I am not sure what you mean by a "general-state-of-affairs 'it'": In both your cases "it" can be identified as (1) the unnamed subject being talked about and (2) the act of juggling. There are also other expressions such as のです which equate to "It is the case that" but that is a bit off topic.

Comment: @Tim I don't recall saying that the literal translation is the only way to translate the sentence. I supplied it to make clear that the sentence is a statement on the general state of affairs, which answers questions (1) and (3). If we agree on that much, there's not much left for me to offer. Cases in which there are more than one way to translate, with respective merits/demerits, are common. So if you choose to translate the sentence as "Hana couldn't say anything to Kayo.", deeming it to be more fitting commentary on the situation, that's your choice as a translator and I respect it.

Comment: @Tim About the It-is-cold sentence: _"It" is not necessarily the place._ That's the very point I wanted to make. You can say "It's cold."/「寒いです。」 in pretty much any context and it'll make sense. You could be talking about the weather, the room you're in, or a place on the other side of the globe. To me, it makes more sense that _It_ refers to some general state of affairs than something that you must identify before you can understand the sentence.

Comment: @3to5businessdays That's a separate phenomenon called [extraposition](http://grammar.about.com/od/e/g/Extraposition.htm). "It is obvious what you are talking about." is equivalent to "What you are talking about is obvious." "It is hard to juggle." is equivalent to "To juggle is hard."/"Juggling is hard."

Comment: @Tim We can discuss more in chat, if you like. I don't have enough rep to open one, so you'll have to.

Comment: "I don't believe this sentence is making a statement about Hana."  But it is despite your belief.

Comment: @非回答者 But 「(それは)…はなでした」 could've easily been 「(それは)…はなと…かよでした」 instead, in the same context. If what それは refers to here is not definite, I'm led to believe that the sentence is more a statement about some general state of affairs. This is in contrast to 「はなは…」, where anything that follows has to be about Hana. Besides, if the topic of the sentence is indeed Hana (in that particular situation), wouldn't it be possible to say 「そのはなは、かよに何も言えないはなでした」as well?